# index for gte, lte and sort in different fields

Tags: mongodb

My query to `mongodb` is:

```
   db.records.find({ from_4: { '$lte': 7495 }, to_4: { '$gte': 7495 } }).sort({ from_11: 1 }).skip(60000).limit(100).hint("from_4_1_to_4_-1_from_11_1").explain()
```

I suggest that it should use index `from_4_1_to_4_-1_from_11_1`

```
{
  "from_4": 1,
  "to_4": -1,
  "from_11": 1
}
```

But got error:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33555322 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes",
    "code" : 17144
} at src/mongo/shell/query.js:131
```

How to avoid this error?

Maybe I should create another index, that better fits my query.

I tried index with all ascending fields too ...

```
{
      "from_4": 1,
      "to_4": 1,
      "from_11": 1
    }
```

... but the same error.

**P.S.** I noticed, that when I remove **skip** command ...

```
> db.records.find({ from_4: { '$lte': 7495 }, to_4: { '$gte': 7495 } }).sort({ from_11: 1 }).limit(100).hint("from_4_1_to_4_-1_from_11_1").explain()
```

...it's ok, I got explain output, but it says that I don't use index: `"indexOnly" : false`

```
{
    "clauses" : [
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor from_4_1_to_4_-1_from_11_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 100,
            "nscannedObjects" : 61868,
            "nscanned" : 61918,
            "scanAndOrder" : true,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "from_4" : [
                    [
                        -Infinity,
                        7495
                    ]
                ],
                "to_4" : [
                    [
                        Infinity,
                        7495
                    ]
                ],
                "from_11" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor ",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 0,
            "nscanned" : 0,
            "scanAndOrder" : true,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "from_4" : [
                    [
                        -Infinity,
                        7495
                    ]
                ],
                "to_4" : [
                    [
                        Infinity,
                        7495
                    ]
                ],
                "from_11" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
    "n" : 100,
    "nscannedObjects" : 61868,
    "nscanned" : 61918,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 61868,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 61918,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "nYields" : 832,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 508,
    "server" : "myMac:27026",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

**P.P.S** I have read  [mongo db tutorial about sort indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/) and think that I do all right.

## Update

accroding **@dark_shadow** advice I created 2 more indexes:

```
db.records.ensureIndex({from_11: 1})

db.records.ensureIndex({from_11: 1, from_4: 1, to_4: 1})
```

and index `db.records.ensureIndex({from_11: 1})` becomes what I need:

```
db.records.find({ from_4: { '$lte': 7495 }, to_4: { '$gte': 7495 } }).sort({ from_11: 1 }).skip(60000).limit(100).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor from_11_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 100,
    "nscannedObjects" : 90154,
    "nscanned" : 90155,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 164328,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 164431,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1284,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 965,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "from_11" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "myMac:27025",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are likely returning a lot of documents and possibly hitting some large ones, thus breaking the 32MB limit. How many results are obtained without the .sort() or .limit() or .skip() modifiers? Also note that this is not indexOnly as you would need to be projecting only the fields that are present in your index. Even an `_id` value present in the document where those were the only fields would prevent this.

Comment: @NeilLunn without sort and limit and skip it returns 61868 records: `db.records.find({ from_4: { '$lte': 7495 }, to_4: { '$gte': 7495 } }).count()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use **range queries** (and you are) mongo query **don't use the index for sorting**  anyway. You can check this by looking at the "scanAndOrder" value of your explain() once you test your query. If that value exists and is true it means it'll sort the resultset in memory (scan and order) rather than use the index directly. This is the reason why you are getting error in your first query.

As the Mongodb documentation says,

**For in-memory sorts that do not use an index, the sort() operation is significantly slower. The sort() operation will abort when it uses 32 megabytes of memory.**

You can check the value of scanAndOrder in your first query by using limit(100) for in memory sorting.

Your second query works because you have used limit so it will sort only 100 documents which can be done in memory.

Why **"indexOnly" : false** ?

This simply indicates that all the fields you wish to return are not in the index, the BtreeCursor indicates that the index was used for the query (a BasicCursor would mean it had not). For this to be an indexOnly query, you would need to be returning only the those fields in the index (that is: {_id : 0,from_4 :1, to_4:1, from_11 :1 }) in your projection. That would mean that it would never have to touch the data itself and could return everything you need from the index alone. You can check this also using the explain once you have modified your query for returning only mentioned fields.

Now, you will be confused. It uses index or not ? For sorting, it won't use the index but for querying it is using the index. That's the reason you get BtreeCusrsor (you should have seen your index name also in that).

Now, to solve your problem you can either create two index:

```
{
      "from_4": 1,
      "to_4": 1,
}

{
    "from_11" : 1
}
```

and then see if it's giving error now or using your index for sorting by carefully observing scanOrder value.

There is one more work around:
Change the order of compund index:

```
{
      "FROM_11" : 1,
      "from_4": 1,
      "to_4": 1,
}
```

NOT SURE ABOUT THIS APPROACH. It should work hopefully.

Looking at what you are trying to get, you can also do sort with {from_11:-1}.limit(1868).

I hope I have made the things a bit clearer now. Please do some testing based on my suggestions. If you face any issues, please let me know. We can work on it.

Thanks